# Azure Emulator shutdown immediately after it started for a web role.

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015

When i run the cloud application locally in storage emulator it starts and shutdown immediately and i have the following error in output console.

> 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'D:\AzureDev\EasyClinicCloudService\csx\Debug\roles\Admin\base\x64\WaIISHost.exe'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime\v4.0_2.7.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\msshrtmi\v4.0_2.7.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\msshrtmi.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WaIISHost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   WaIISHost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. The program '[6124] WaIISHost.exe' has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0).

and when i check my Waiishost log it looks like..

> WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00006124:00000001, 2016-06-13
>   13:54:36.312, INFO ] Starting host process. WaIISHost Information: 0 :
>   [00006124:00000001, 2016-06-13 13:54:36.365, INFO ]
>   DebuggerAttachStart START WaIISHost Information: 0 :
>   [00006124:00000001, 2016-06-13 13:54:36.366, INFO ]
>   DebuggerAttachStart END WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00006124:00000001,
>   2016-06-13 13:54:36.376, INFO ] Found role model xml file WaIISHost
>   Information: 0 : [00006124:00000001, 2016-06-13 13:54:36.402, INFO ]
>   Creating endpoint IPAddress:127.0.0.1 PortNum:83  Protocol:http
>   HostHeader: WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00006124:00000001, 2016-06-13
>   13:54:36.402, INFO ] Adding site to AppModel with name , endpoints
>   http:127.0.0.1:83: WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00006124:00000001,
>   2016-06-13 13:54:36.435, INFO ] Reacl all resources for iis users
>   WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00006124:00000001, 2016-06-13
>   13:54:36.442, INFO ] Reacl all resources for iis users has been
>   finished. WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00006124:00000001, 2016-06-13
>   13:54:36.443, INFO ] Wait for iisconfigurator initialization global
>   event to be set WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00006124:00000001,
>   2016-06-13 13:54:36.443, INFO ] Found iisconfigurator initialization
>   global event WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00006124:00000001, 2016-06-13
>   13:54:36.443, INFO ] Iisconfigurator initialization global event set
>   WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00006124:00000001, 2016-06-13
>   13:54:36.457, INFO ] Changing operation timeout to 00:05:00 WaIISHost
>   Information: 0 : [00006124:00000001, 2016-06-13 13:54:36.465, INFO ]
>   Attempt Deploy with
>   RoleInstanceId=deployment29(79).EasyClinicCloudService.Admin_IN_0
>   RoleRoot=D:\AzureDev\EasyClinicCloudService\csx\Debug\roles\Admin\
>   optional SitesDestination= WaIISHost Information: 0 :
>   [00006124:00000001, 2016-06-13 13:54:38.066, ERROR]
>   Exception:System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   Invalid name. Parameter name: name (Fault Detail is equal to An
>   ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.ArgumentException: Invalid name. Parameter name: name    at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType
>   resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle,
>   AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName,
>   ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object
>   exceptionContext)    at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity..ctor(Boolean
>   isContainer, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections,
>   Boolean isDirectory)    at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity..ctor(String name,
>   AccessControlSections includeSections)    at
>   System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections
>   includeSections)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.FileManager.AddAllowAceIterative(DirectoryInfo
>   dir, FileSystemRights rights, IdentityReference[] accounts)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurato...).
>
> WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00006124:00000001, 2016-06-13
>   13:54:38.073, ERROR]
>   Exception:System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   Invalid name. Parameter name: name (Fault Detail is equal to An
>   ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.ArgumentException: Invalid name. Parameter name: name    at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType
>   resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle,
>   AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName,
>   ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object
>   exceptionContext)    at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity..ctor(Boolean
>   isContainer, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections,
>   Boolean isDirectory)    at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity..ctor(String name,
>   AccessControlSections includeSections)    at
>   System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections
>   includeSections)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.FileManager.AddAllowAceIterative(DirectoryInfo
>   dir, FileSystemRights rights, IdentityReference[] accounts)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurato...).

i am using vs 2015 and azure sdk 2.9
I am really stuck with this please suggest me a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by simply removing node_modules from application. I remove node_modules by using following command.

1-> npm install rimraf -g

2-> rimraf node_modules

at the time i removed it's working fine now.

I have tried to update node version to 3.x but that not work for me.

please suggest is there any way to keep node_modules as it is and run.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quite similar issue. In my case, anytime I started the Cosmos Db Emulator, I receive a notification "Shutting down" and then the icon disappears.

I repaired it and also uninstalled and installed it again but it still persisted.

Later, along the line it worked for me after browsing to `"C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe"` path and running the emulator manually.
I think it wasn't working for me initially but it worked.

Thanks.